# No exported member "eDomAnimationEngine"

Tags: angular, animation

I'm using animation on angular 4.0.0 and manually install package "@angular/animation" but after that I got issue, could you point me what wrong am I and any solutions?
I've appreciate.

Link screen shot:  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/szdAo.jpg

Comment: Try this: "@angular/animations": "4.1.3"